# How do I use a dynamic object in JDBC application

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

The query is working fine in MySQL db. I have this query in my JDBC application. And I'm getting some compile time error.
My input objects are *s1* and *s2*, where **s1 contains january** and **s2 contains 2013**. Both datatypes are VARCHAR. I am facing a problem in quotes. 
Please suggest some correction.

`String QueryString = "SELECT reading,totalcost,paiddate,receiptnumber

FROM userseven WHERE (readingmonth = '"+s1+"' AND readingyear='"+s2+"'");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should better use `PreparedStatement`for such purpose. So your query will look like this:

```
 String QueryString = "SELECT reading,totalcost,paiddate,receiptnumber FROM userseven WHERE
 readingmonth = ? AND readingyear= ?;
```

Then create  `PreparedStatement` from `connection` object like this:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(QueryString);
```

And then set parameters for that statement like this:

```
stmt.setString(1, s1);
stmt.setString(2, s2);
```

Such modifications will save you from potential sql injection and simply simplify the process of building complex query

Comment: maks using result set how to execute the prepare statement    String QueryString = "SELECT reading,totalcost,paiddate,receiptnumber FROM userseven WHERE readingmonth = ? AND readingyear= ?";
          PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(QueryString);
          stmt.setString(1, s1);
          stmt.setString(2, s2);
          rs = statement.executeQuery(stmt);//in this query correct
    while (rs.next()) {
     
   
      rs.getString(1);
      rs.getString(2);
      rs.getString(3);}

Comment: @KRISH You need to use [`PreparedStatement.executeQuery()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery()). Please check the Javadocs and follow the [JDBC Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html)